# bootstrap css: can i have reference from CDN and folder path both in a same page?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have reference of bootstrap files in my HTML from CDN:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

I also have my own custom css file reference in HTML from folder path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyles.css">
```

But it seems like the style rules from my custom css file not working. Is this illegal way of giving reference ? What should be the proper way ?

Here is my own css style:

```
.row-header {
margin:0px auto;
padding:0px auto;
}

.row-content {
margin:0px auto;
padding:50px 0px 50px 0px;
border-bottom:1px ridge;
min-height:400px;
}

 .row-footer {
backgroud-color:#AfAfAf;
margin:0px auto;
padding:20px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.jumbotron {
padding:70px 30px 70px 30px;
margin:0px auto;
backgroud:#7986CB;
color:floralwhite;
}

address {
font-size:80%;
margin:0px;
color:#0f0f0f;
}
```

Comment: make sure you include your style after the bootstrap styles!

Comment: @sebastianbrosch its not the case; already arranged in proper way.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @Vucko No error! page is fine with bootstrap styles; only my styles not working

Comment: And your custom styles affect bootstraps or not? Try adding `!important` on your custom styles.

Comment: @Vucko doesn't work :(

Comment: [Check the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ho9v52n/1/)

Comment: wrong syntax! don't place the `!important` on the beginning of the file. set it like this: `background-color:#000 !important;`

Comment: @Vucko works in the fiddle! surprisingly not the same in browser. any idea ?

Comment: @Tito.S.Roy well, it must work. Can you create your fiddle?

Comment: Change this `backgroud-color:#AfAfAf;` to this `background-color: #afafaf;` your background color is not been applied cause you spelled it wrong on the class of `.row-footer`

Comment: @Vucko The problem is definitely with reference of the custom css file. when i put my css codes inside <style></style> in HTML it is working fine; as we can see in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/myCustom.css">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
    <body>
    <div calss="row-header">Header Content</div>
    <div class="row-content">Row Content</div>
    <div class="jumbotron"><p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#fork">Fork this fiddle</a></div>
    <address>Address</address>

    <div class="custom">
            <p>Put me to the right on the browser</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row-footer">Footer Content</div>
    <!--scripts at the bottom-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--//scripts-->
    </body>
</html>
```

and for your CSS

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
.custom {
    float: right;
} 
.row-header {
margin:0px auto;
padding:0px auto;
}

.row-content {
margin:0px auto;
padding:50px 0px 50px 0px;
border-bottom:1px ridge;
min-height:400px;
}

.row-footer {
#backgroud-color:#AfAfAf;
background-color: #afafaf;
margin:0px auto;
padding:20px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.jumbotron {
padding:70px 30px 70px 30px;
margin:0px auto;
#backgroud:#7986CB;
background: #7986CB;
color:floralwhite;
}

address {
font-size:80%;
margin:0px;
color:#0f0f0f;
}
```

This should help you. Copy and paste the code on new file and test it. I hope this will help you.

Comment: The problem is definitely with the reference of the custom css file. when I put my css codes inside <style></style> in HTML it is working fine; as we can see in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Did you remove the `!important` that @sebastianbrosch was talking about?

You are not suppose to do that. Also check your css extension.

Comment: ahhh the problem is with css extension. I'm using sublime text and the default extension was set to .cs for c# files for some unknown reasons. @Jay Star Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Tito.S.Roy I'm glad that did help you.